# Server speed: sharing one script.php or using many copies the same script.php

Tags: apache-2.2, php, load-balancing, performance

Let's assume:

1. I have **thousands** of domains on same Apache server.
2. Each domain is in a folder under server public_html document folder, so it can be accessed by calling "www.somedomain.com" or by calling "www.serverdomain.com/somedomain_folder"
3. In each domain there is a website who needs a certain script.php (identical for each domain).

From a coding point view, its obvious that it's better to use a unique script.php, so when i update it with new features/bug fixes etc, I need to update on server only one file and it will work for all domains.

But from a server point of view? 
**If i use a unique script all domains will access it at the same time, will the server run slower compared to the situation where each domain called its own script?**

Comment: I think this would fall into "micro-optimization" the benefit you will see from either method is not worth the trouble of implementing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use a unique script all domains
>   will access it at the same time, will
>   the server run slower compared to the
>   situation where each domain called its
>   own script?

I think it's the other way round. **It shouldn't be slower**. The question is, "*will running it shared make it faster*"? As to that point - theoretically, **yes**. But the practical difference may be indiscernible.

The point is - if there's **one script only** for all users (the idea of shared libraries) it's not only easier to maintain as pointed out earlier here, but the **built-in caching** mechanisms should be more efficient (at least from my understanding of the subject). One file to read, easy way to cache in memory. Multiple identical files (not sym-/hardlinked, different *inodes*) - this is more problematic. Or am I underestimating *Linux* capabilities here? Please correct me if I'm wrong - my knowledge of the internals is not that profound, but I think this would result in independent seeks/buffering.

Another point - using **opcode caches**. I'm not sure about how it looks in different implementations, but in most cases using multiple identical scripts would result in **unnecessary cache entries**. However, there's one potential problem with shared scripts - when caching gets too aggressive (like caching external configuration files between different users). I had recently encountered this kind of behaviour with [XCache and hardlinks](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/ticket/117). With proper configuration and non-buggy implementations it's not a problem though.

So, my **conclusion**:

If it's feasible, I would use **shared installations** both for **convenience** and **performance**. However, in some situations the difference in performance can be negligible, so it's probably "*what fits your situation better*".

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it is best to put that script in your server's **[PHP include path](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/php-include-path.html)** and use it in all your websites.

I don't think maintaining copies for each domain will result in speed improvement. If you DO notice slowdown when using a common script, try various **php/apache caching modules** to speed things up a little.

And yes, as you said, you can update in one place and all websites will use the updated php script. This particular convenience outweighs many many other alternatives.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the link, very inetersting I didn't know about the PHP include path could be loaded also using php.ini or .htaccess, very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience using a shared directory of common modules won't slow your server down, otherwise you would have a unique copy of all PHP libraries for all domains.

Comment: That's make sense too, +1 and thanks.